# Mail gui stretching (Freya/Loki)

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-mail

I'm a big fan of Elementary OS and have been around since Freya. Recently loaded Loki to a new development box... I think it's great (after a bit of tweaking: ppa, gdebi, etc). Updates are current as of this posting.

Please take anything that appears to be critical with a grain of salt. Love the OS. Everything is mostly fast, sweet and very well designed. Not going anywhere...

That being said, I've had a strange recurring gui issue with Geary/Pantheon-Mail across both releases. Massive stretching that makes Mail impossible to use. Popped up after a few days on Freya, took a week or so to happen with Loki.

Interesting differences: Freya stretching occurred instantly (when it occurred); it was also very large, horizontally (can't really guess at the pixel width).

Loki Mail stretched almost comically: it started loading, then started stretching in front of my eyes like Stretch Armstrong (image below). I really like the email client itself, so it would be great if we could figure this out.

Is this a GTK issue?

Here's the money, with a terminal for scale:

[image: Mail stretch in Loki]

Comment: What triggers the stretching? Do you have any video or logs after the unexpected behavior that would be helpful? There's a good chance this will end with a bug report

Comment: On Freya it was instant open. Loki Mail animated...

I mentioned in a different thread on a similar issue that both of my installs are Lenovo development laptops -- the Loki build on an upgraded x220. 

But since I've seen the same behavior on both (and it doesn't appear to be a terribly common issue) I wonder if it isn't tied to Lenovo drivers/gtk?

Comment: @Chris Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Follow the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1631672

Comment: @Fly Unfortunately, no. Still having the issue. Are you also on a Lenovo? (Many thanks Wolf for the bug report)

Comment: Update: Still stretched horizontally, but now somewhat better vertically (not entirely, but now shows three emails instead of one, so it seems they're working on it)

Comment: @Chris Yes, I have a Lenovo. Typing dconf reset -f /org/pantheon/mail/ into a terminal worked.